# this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl is not a function while using ngx-image-cropper

Tags: angular

I am using ngx-image-cropper@1.3.8 in my angular 6 app. I want to my cropper be loaded with an existing image. I am using imageBase64 property of the cropper. I am converting an imageUrl to base64 string and assiging to the cropper. Everything is working fine locally. But in server i am getting bypassSecurityResourceUrl error. And i figured out that this error is generated inside the cropper package. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code

```
<image-cropper mat-card-image class="inner-cropper" [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
            [maintainAspectRatio]="false" [aspectRatio]="1/1" [imageQuality]="50" format="jpeg"
            *ngIf="base64string && hasPicture" [imageBase64]="base64string" (imageCroppedBase64)="imageCropped($event)"
            (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded()" (imageCroppedFile)="imageCroppedFile($event)"
            (loadImageFailed)="loadImageFailed()">
</image-cropper>
```

Here is my sanitize in component level.
I am doing like below...

```
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private _sanitizer:DomSanitizer)

getBase64(imgUrl) {
        const self = this;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("get", imgUrl, true);
        // Essential
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                var blob = this.response;
                console.log("blob", blob)
                let oFileReader = new FileReader();
                oFileReader.onloadend = function (e) {
                    let base64 = e.target;
                    self.base64string = self._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl((<any>base64).result);

                };
                oFileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);

            }
        }

    }
```

I am getting this error

> ERROR TypeError: this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl is not
> a function
> at t.loadBase64Image (main.70f08624b0a556d33c40.js:1)
> at t.set [as imageBase64] (main.70f08624b0a556d33c40.js:1)
> at Cr (main.70f08624b0a556d33c40.js:1)
> at main.70f08624b0a556d33c40.js:1
> at main.70f08624b0a556d33c40.js:1
> at Zr (main.70f08624b0a556d33c40.js:1)
> at wa (main.70f08624b0a556d33c40.js:1)
> at Object.updateDirectives (main.70f08624b0a556d33c40.js:1)
> at Object.updateDirectives (main.70f08624b0a556d33c40.js:1)
> at Kr (main.70f08624b0a556d33c40.js:1)

the issue in this line in ngx-imager-cropper package

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5UeR.png)

Comment: what does your class look like?

Comment: did you mean ImageCropperComponent class?

Comment: yes, because you need to make sure that you are importing and properly declating the `sanitizer` in order to use it. Also, I don't see where you are using the `sanitizer`

Comment: I have edited the post. you may check now. But i repeat again the error i have got generated in ngx-image-cropper package. And Everything is working fine locally. But in server i got this error.